# Scroll without changing the cursor position

Tags: scrolling

Frequently when using vim I will hit a case where I am looking at a function that is half off the bottom of the screen, and I would like to see the whole thing. `ctrl-D` will generally solve the problem visually, but it also moves my cursor. If I was already at the top of the function, I'd like to stay there, just see the whole thing. Is there a version of `ctrl-D` that acts more like `ctrl-e`, or even better, a command sequence that would center whatever function my cursor is currently in?

I'm using vim in at least three places: native GNOME Terminal on Fedora, native Terminal on OS X, and in both places occasionally over ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zt for keeping cursor at the top, zb for bottom and zz for middle; furthermore, you can find out more about these by using :h command